# What is the difference between **could + have p.p.** and **could + infinitive**?

Tags: modal-verbs, usage, perfect-aspect

> We could not imagine how the Inca **could have built** such a large
>   city on top of a high mountain.

I don't think **could build** can replace **could have built** in the sentence above, but I am not sure why not.

What is the difference between **could + have p.p.** and **could + infinitive**?

I learned from a previous post in this site that **could + have p.p.** could mean *inference or deduction of past possibility*. And **could + infinitive** could mean *present or past possibility*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

- *We **could** not imagine how the Inca **could have** done that.*
  (let's just concentrate on the modals here, OK?)

is grammatical, and means the same as the sentence

- *We **could** not imagine how the Inca **could** do that.*

Both refer to past times, but the first one overtly specifies the time of the Inca's actions as prior to the time of our failure to imagine them, while the second one doesn't.

In a case where the context makes the order of events obvious (the Inca's actions are in the far past, whereas we're still alive), it's not necessary to specify it overtly.

If you **do** specify that order when you don't need to, you draw attention to it. This may be what you want to do; or it may be unnecessary detail that slows down the reader/listener's understanding of your point.

The choice is, as usual, up to the writer/speaker, who has a better idea than anybody else of what they want the reader/listener to understand, and how to achieve it.

Neither sentence is subjunctive, by the way. Just more modal auxiliary usages, that's all.

Comment: I liked this answer and I got a question for you! How should I know here "could" is the past form of can not a present tense modal impying a week possibility? Also, why shouldn't I understand the sentence as the author is not sure if they actually built the city? I mean why shouldn't I get "could have built" as "they might build"; like they could have called me but they didn't!

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is in the subjunctive mood. The sentence does not cast doubt on the fact that the Inca built the city, it merely says that it was difficult for the writer to imagine how this was accomplished.

you can replace 'could have built' with 'could build' but the new sentence could be interpreted as casting doubt on the fact that the Inca built the city.

I agree with what you learned from a previous post.